# The center of a minimal convex superbody

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convexity

Is the following true?

**CONJECTURE:** $\,$ Let $\ B\ C\subseteq\mathbb R^n\ $ be convex bodies in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\ C\ $ is centrally symmetric, $\ B\subseteq C,\ $ and $\ t\!\cdot\! B\ $ cannot be isometrically embedded in $\ C,\ $ for no $\ t>1.\ $ Then the center $c(C)$ of $C$ must belong to $B$, $\ c(C)\in B$.

---

> *Thank you Douglas Z. for pointing out the mess in my earlier formulation.*
>
> *Sorry for a series of additional omissions. (Now the text is complete, I hope).*

**EDIT** (*after solutions of the original conjecture, by katz and Wlodek K)*--As Wlodek Kuperberg has observed, an additional assumption about the n-dim volume (or area in 2-dim) of $B$ and $C$:

$$ |C|\ \le\ 2\cdot|B| $$

makes the conjecture true even without the earlier assumption about enlargement of $B$ (nor about symmetry).

Comment: body $\,=\,$ compact + n-dimensional

Comment: From the title I would guess that you have an inclusion reversed, and you want to allow translations of $tB$.

Comment: @DouglasZare, thank you. There is a lot of noise between my brain and my typing fingers. What's worse, there is (sometimes :-) a lot of noise in my poor brain as well. I'll edit my Q.

Comment: What does " $\ B\ C\subseteq\mathbb R^n\ $" mean? That both $B$ and $C$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, or that some product of $B$ and $C$ is?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, *** $\ B\ C\ \subseteq \mathbb R^n\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \left(\left(B\ \subseteq \mathbb R^n\right) \wedge\left(C\ \subseteq \mathbb R^n\right)\right)\ $ ***

Comment: For any $B$ not containing the center of $C$, we can expand it to almost half of $C$, on one side of a hyperplane through the center. The question is whether any such almost-half of a centrally symmetric figure can be repositioned inside $C$ to cover the center. This should not be the case if you take a skew slice through the center of a cube, but I haven't yet proved that no rotation works.

Comment: It is much more conventional and understandable to write $B, C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, "bodies" is plural (and $\mathbb R^n$ is not a convex body). At least it was not impossible.

Comment: It is unclear to me where the assumptions end and the statement (that you want to prove) begins. A full stop (.) and/or a connecting word (e.g. 'then') would be useful.

Comment: Yes, "bodies" is plural, and I had understood how you are defining that term. Please take my previous comment as a helpful suggestion; Joseph's confusion was understandable.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, I apologize for missing the conclusion in my version which you have just seen--I lost this during the editing session. Now I hope that everything is finally fine.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, thank you for your justified (at least relatively) criticism. On the other hand Joseph (above) was a bit overdoing it, I'd think. :)

Comment: There is a slight variation that I think is better: Suppose no larger isometric copy of $B$ fits in $C$. Must some isometric copy of $B$ inside $C$ contain the center of $C$? This would rule out the counterexample by katz, and the disk in a rectangle, but I think there are other counterexamples starting in $\mathbb{R}^3$. This is true if you replace isometry with translation.

Comment: @DouglasZare, thank you for this and all your comments. Your suggestion is interesting (and to me--weird, which is good -). I'll stop to think about it. On the other hand my own completion of the conjecture seems to me boringly natural (however, this time it may be harder?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C$ be a $3\times 1$ rectangle centered at the origin, and $B$ a $1\times 1$ square "filling" the left side of $C$.  Then $tB$ cannot be embedded in $C$ if $t>1$ but $B$ does not contain the origin, disproving the conjecture.

Comment: It turns out that Wlodek Kuperberg has posted a similar counter-example to my conjecture on FB about 3h before the katz's solution on MO. He had a unit disk inside a $5x2$ rectangle. Each example has its own subtle advantages (while my conjecture was rather easy--after the fact).